# GroupBy Datepart function missing data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

So I have a query that I'm trying to find sums and averages while grouping by the timestamp down to the minute.  However, if the timestamp has the SAME minute but in a different hour, that rows data doesn't show up.  Below is my query and the output and what the individual rows are:

```
NumCardsPassed  ProcessingTime  ProcessingDate
     10              4         2016-08-29 11:13:44.000
      1              0         2016-08-29 11:49:43.000
      2              1         2016-08-29 12:19:42.000
```

and here are the individual rows with out all the grouping.  Notice how the timestamp of 12:13 and 22:13 is missing in the above query (NumCardsPassed above should equal 10 instead, it added it to 11:13 numcards passed at 10)

```
NumCardsPassed      ProcessingTime     processingdate
     1                    2         2016-08-29 11:13:44.000
     1                    0         2016-08-29 11:49:43.000
     8                    10        2016-08-29 12:13:44.000
     1                    3         2016-08-29 12:19:42.000
     1                    0         2016-08-29 22:13:47.000

Select  sum(numcardspassed) as "NumCardsPassed", 
avg(processingtime) as "ProcessingTime",  min(ProcessingDate) as "ProcessingDate" 
From orderprocessormetrics
where ProcessingDate >= '8/27/2016' and ProcessingDate < '8/30/2016' and PreprocessorType = 'SOP' and numcardsPassed > 0 and clientid = 6820
Group by  DatePart(minute, orderprocessormetrics.processingdate) 
order by processingdate
```

So basically since that datePart is based on minutes, it's grouping all the rows with the same minutes together regardless of hours.  Is there a way to take into account hours and date and not just minutes.  I still need it to group by minutes and not seconds or milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (nice name btw lol) :

```
Select  sum(numcardspassed) as "NumCardsPassed", sum(numcardsfailed) as "NumCardsFailed",  
avg(processingtime) as "ProcessingTime",  min(ProcessingDate) as "ProcessingDate" 
From orderprocessormetrics
where ProcessingDate >= '8/27/2016' and ProcessingDate < '8/30/2016' and PreprocessorType = 'SOP' and numcardsPassed > 0 and clientid = 6820
Group by  convert(varchar, ProcessingDate, 108) 
order by processingdate
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, if the timestamp has the SAME minute but in a different hour, that rows data doesn't show up

try this..

```
group by 
DatePart(minute, orderprocessormetrics.processingdate),
DatePart(hour, orderprocessormetrics.processingdate),
DatePart(day, orderprocessormetrics.processingdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to truncate the date/time to the minute.  Here is one way:

```
select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, processingdate), 0) as to_the_minute,
       sum(numcardspassed) as NumCardsPassed, 
       avg(processingtime) as ProcessingTime
From orderprocessormetrics
where ProcessingDate >= '2016-08-27' and ProcessingDate < '2016-08-30' and 
      PreprocessorType = 'SOP' and
      numcardsPassed > 0 and
      clientid = 6820
group by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, processingdate), 0)
order by to_the_minute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query..

```
Select  sum(numcardspassed) as "NumCardsPassed", 
avg(processingtime) as "ProcessingTime",  min(ProcessingDate) as "ProcessingDate" 
From orderprocessormetrics
where ProcessingDate >= '8/27/2016' and ProcessingDate < '8/30/2016' and PreprocessorType = 'SOP' and numcardsPassed > 0 and clientid = 6820
Group by  CAST(orderprocessormetrics.processingdate as date)
,DatePart(hour, orderprocessormetrics.processingdate) 
,DatePart(minute, orderprocessormetrics.processingdate) 
order by processingdate
```